# ArcMap stopped working after trying to open table of contents

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, table

I use ArcMap 10.8.1. Recently it stops working and crashes.
There is a trigger for the crash - **Table of contents.** When I open the program, it doesn't show, but when I try to open the table of content, it crashes.
I've tried to do all the steps I found on Stack Exchange, but it didn't work.
I even tried to uninstall and reinstall ArcMap, but it still crashes.

How can I solve this issue?

Comment: You mean the attribute table?

Comment: When you say crashes do you mean that you get a Serious Application Error?

Comment: Have you tried renaming/deleting the Normal.mxt?

Comment: Normal.mxt resides @ C:\Users\{current user}\AppData\Roaming\ESRI\Desktop10.xxx\ArcMap\Templates